# Initialize RcppZiggurat RNG-Generator on snow cluster

Tags: r, random, parallel-processing, rcpp, snow

I'm trying to use the RNG of the package RcppZiggurat on a snow cluster. To seed the RNG on each node, I use L'Ecuyer's algorithm built into clusterSetupRNG. However, the sequence of random numbers turns out to be the same on each node. The result of the code stays exactly the same even if I run it without the clusterSetupRNG-command.

Here's what I tried:

```
library(RcppZiggurat)
library(snow)

myFun <- function(i){
    rn <- zrnormLZLLV(10)
    return(rn)
}

nodes <- rep("localhost",2)

cl <- makeCluster(nodes, type="SOCK")
vars <- list("zrnormLZLLV")
clusterExport(cl=cl,list=vars,envir=environment())
clusterSetupRNG(cl=cl,type="RNGstream")

res <- parLapply(cl,c(1,2,3,4),myFun)
res
```

Does anybody have an idea how I can make this work? Of course I could always resort to the standard RNG rnorm, but it would be nice to have the speed of RcppZiggurat also on a cluster.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Did you _actually install my RcppZiggurat package on each node_ so that the different tasks can access it?

Comment: Hi @Dirk, thanks for your suggestion. If I load RcppZiggurat on each node using `clusterEvalQ(cl=cl,library(RcppZiggurat))` instead of just exporting the function `zrnormLZLLV`, I still get the same sequence or random numbers on each node.

Comment: Use a different seed on each node.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Using `clusterApply(cl=cl,seq(1,2,by=1),zsetseedLZLLV)` works just fine.